# Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu error installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, acpi

I try to set up Ubuntu in my dell precision laptop (Windows 10). But when my laptop boots Ubuntu from USB, this error occurs:

```
APCI BIOS Error(bug): Failure creating...
```

and besides the error messages, the screen is black.

I have turned off APCI = off, and it starts to Ubuntu setup, but in installation type, I haven't seen any partition and couldn't click on install now.

---

No partition:

[image: Ubuntu installer showing no partitions]

Ubuntu setup errors:

[image: screenshot showing some kernel messages]

Comment: I don't know enough to be able to say what is wrong. But I can give general pointers. Do you have a gparted live disk? If so if you boot that you will see your partition layout. Could be bootloader having gone. Could be bios settings. Could be a bad usb stick.

Comment: If i buy a new SDD and install ubuntu on this SDD, can i solve problem?